# Convert access query with right outer join to sqlite query

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, outer-join

`SELECT t13_Literature_Material_Codes.Databank, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_NUMB, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_SYMB, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_CHAR, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_MOLW, CorrosionRatesInfo.RatesValidFlag
FROM CorrosionRatesInfo RIGHT JOIN t13_Literature_Material_Codes ON CorrosionRatesInfo.BASE_NUMB=t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_NUMB;`

how can I do this query in sqlite? I saw people used left outer join. please provide a solution using similar structure, my c++ program can then modify the query string with a easy parser process.

Answer (score 0):

To perform this Query in Sqlite:

```
SELECT t13_Literature_Material_Codes.Databank, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_NUMB, 
t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_SYMB, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_CHAR, 
t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_MOLW, CorrosionRatesInfo.RatesValidFlag FROM 
CorrosionRatesInfo RIGHT OUTER JOIN t13_Literature_Material_Codes ON  
CorrosionRatesInfo.BASE_NUMB=t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_NUMB;
```

Just you need to add "RIGHT OUTER JOIN" .

Comment: I tried "right outer join" but I got Error: RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported

Comment: "SELECT t13_Literature_Material_Codes.Databank, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_NUMB, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_SYMB, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_CHAR, t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_MOLW, CorrosionRatesInfo.RatesValidFlag
    FROM t13_Literature_Material_Codes LEFT JOIN CorrosionRatesInfo on CorrosionRatesInfo.BASE_NUMB=t13_Literature_Material_Codes.BASE_NUMB"







It worked! I swapped the table names and change "right join" to "left join"

Answer (score 0):

User UNION  to solve this problem

For Example

```
SELECT employee.*, department.*
FROM   employee 
       LEFT JOIN department 
          ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID
UNION ALL
SELECT employee.*, department.*
FROM   department
       LEFT JOIN employee
          ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID
WHERE  employee.DepartmentID IS NULL
```

Yes, [see the example on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full%5Fouter%5Fjoin)